# changing time format objective c

Tags: objective-c, datetime-format

i"m fetching time from server in this format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a" and converting it to this format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a". While converting, time goes an hour before the original time.

This the time I fetched from server
Date Created 29-Jun-2017 01:44:43 PM 
And converted time 
Date Modified 29-06-2017 12:44 PM

Can anyone help me to remove seconds from time fetched from server

Comment: `HH:mm a` `HH` + `a`? `hh:mm a` instead no? For the rest, it's a timezone issue I guess.

Comment: I meant "HH" => 24h formats. "a": "AM/PM". But "AM/PM" make sense only if you use 12h format, no? It's to differenciate 14h = 2hPM to 2h = 2hAM ?

Comment: You can accept the answer which works for you. @SherineSJ

Answer (score 3):

You can set the time zone of your date formatter like this:

```
[gmtDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Sample:

```
NSString *str = @"29-Jun-2017 01:44:43 PM";
NSDateFormatter* gmtDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtDf setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[gmtDf setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate* gmtDate = [gmtDf dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@",gmtDate);
```

Other time zones names:

```
    ADT = "America/Halifax";
    AKDT = "America/Juneau";
    AKST = "America/Juneau";
    ART = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";
    AST = "America/Halifax";
    BDT = "Asia/Dhaka";
    BRST = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BRT = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    BST = "Europe/London";
    CAT = "Africa/Harare";
    CDT = "America/Chicago";
    CEST = "Europe/Paris";
    CET = "Europe/Paris";
    CLST = "America/Santiago";
    CLT = "America/Santiago";
    COT = "America/Bogota";
    CST = "America/Chicago";
    EAT = "Africa/Addis_Ababa";
    EDT = "America/New_York";
    EEST = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EET = "Europe/Istanbul";
    EST = "America/New_York";
    GMT = GMT;
    GST = "Asia/Dubai";
    HKT = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
    HST = "Pacific/Honolulu";
    ICT = "Asia/Bangkok";
    IRST = "Asia/Tehran";
    IST = "Asia/Calcutta";
    JST = "Asia/Tokyo";
    KST = "Asia/Seoul";
    MDT = "America/Denver";
    MSD = "Europe/Moscow";
    MSK = "Europe/Moscow";
    MST = "America/Denver";
    NZDT = "Pacific/Auckland";
    NZST = "Pacific/Auckland";
    PDT = "America/Los_Angeles";
    PET = "America/Lima";
    PHT = "Asia/Manila";
    PKT = "Asia/Karachi";
    PST = "America/Los_Angeles";
    SGT = "Asia/Singapore";
    UTC = UTC;
    WAT = "Africa/Lagos";
    WEST = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WET = "Europe/Lisbon";
    WIT = "Asia/Jakarta";
```